# Cannot import any module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pip, python-import

Python libraries are giving error on importing them.Almost all library are giving same error. This is the case for simple pip module as well as pandas,etc.

1.Pip

```
$python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2  
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
vendored("cachecontrol")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
__import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 3, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 35, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 14, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 80, in <module>
import mimetools
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
import tempfile
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
from random import Random as _Random
File "random.py", line 2
hvsbiav
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the traceback, it seems that you have an incorrect indentation in your `random.py` file. Try looking at the [original](https://svn.python.org/projects/stackless/trunk/Lib/random.py) file and match your contents with it.

However, if the problem still persists you can try to force re-install a Python package using:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall <packagename>
```

Or, you could re-install Python 2.7 using:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7
```